# Generating random numbers code

Tags: c, random

I have a function generating random numbers. Why does it always generate the same ones? I tried running the algorithm several times but always get the same results.

```
#ifndef UTIL_H
#define UTIL_H

#include <time.h>
#include <sys/time.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define MIN 0
#define MAX 100000


void randomArray (double *array, int length)
{
    int i ;  
    for (i = 0; i < length; i++) 
    {
        array[i] = (double) (rand () /
                   (((double) RAND_MAX + 1) / (double) (MAX - MIN + 1))) + MIN;
    }
}

int main(void) 
{
    int i;
    double test_array[9];

    randomArray(test_array,  9);    

    for(i = 0; i < 9; i++)
        printf("%f ", test_array[i]);
    printf("\n");

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 6):

You need to seed the rand function. Use `srand(time(NULL))` in the beginning of your `main`.

Answer (score 1):

**There are 3 problems in your code:**

**1)** Add `srand` to your `main()` function:

```
int main(void) {
    int i;
    double test_array[9];

    srand (time(NULL));        // here it is

    randomArray(test_array,  9);

    for(i = 0; i < 9; i++)
        printf("%f ", test_array[i]);
    printf("\n");

    return 0;
}
```

**2)** Add an `stdio.h` library for using `printf()`:

```
#include <stdio.h>
```

**3)** There is *unterminated `#ifndef`* that will couse an error when compiling.
   Add `#endif`:

```
#ifndef UTIL_H
#define UTIL_H
#endif             // here it is
```